# On uniform number generation with vectors

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $\vec{a}$ be a random unitary vector. If $\vec{\lambda}$ is a uniformly distributed vector on $\mathbb{S}_2$ (the unitary sphere?), could we say that the result $|\vec{a}.\vec{\lambda}|$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ ?

**Edit** (following jkn's comment) :

And what if we do it with $\vec{\lambda}$ uniformly distributed on the unit ball instead of the unit sphere ?

PS : here is a [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0507120.pdf) to the article where I found this. They assume this at III. B., page 5.

Comment: No, just look at what happens in one and two dimensions.

Comment: Do you mean on the unit sphere or the unit ball (which includes the interior of the spheres)?

Comment: @jkn In the article I read, they say $\vec{\lambda}\in S_2$ (but it's a $S$ like $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @jkn I found the character. It's $\vec{\lambda}$ uniformly distributed on $\mathbb{S}_2$

Comment: $\mathbb{S}_2$ usually denotes the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In which case, what is the difference between the distribution of $a$ and that of $\lambda$? Maybe you could post a link to the article?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Keep in mind the definition of the dot product.

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = (a)(b)\cos(\theta)$

Clearly your example will not be uniformly distributed

Comment: And if as @jkn said, we do it on the unit ball instead?